# Gradle task to compile Java and Groovy sources

Tags: java, maven, gradle, groovy

We are starting a new Project with gradle (all of my previous projects are on Maven) and this is my first experience on using gradle, below is my `build.gradle` file and am trying to compile the `java` and `groovy` sources using the task `compile`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
        springVersion = '4.3.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


task compile(type: GroovyCompile) {
    //source = fileTree(dir: 'src', include: '**/*.java')
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java { srcDirs = [] }    // no source dirs for the java compiler
            groovy { srcDir "src" }  // compile everything in src/ with groovy
        }
    }
    destinationDir = file('build/classes/main')

    classpath = files('build/classes/main')
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.10"
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs:${springBootVersion}')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-groovy-templates:${springBootVersion}')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:${springBootVersion}')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:${springBootVersion}')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${springVersion}')
    compile "com.microsoft:sqljdbc4:4.0"
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}')
}
```

And when I run the `gradle compile` command am seeing `:compile NO-SOURCE` and no compiled classes in `build\classes\main`

can someone please help me with gradle task to compile both `java` and `groovy` sources?

Comment: Did you use Spring Initializr to generate this? By default, it includes some source files that should show you the location (generally `src/main/*`).

Comment: Why are you messing with paths and stuff? Just include the Groovy plugin, and stick your Java in src/main/java and your Groovy in src/main/groovy no need for all the stuff you have above...

Answer (score 0):

The [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html) of the Groovy plugin describe the default layout like follows. If it is an option to stick to that, there is no need for a custom compile task.

```
src/main/java       Production Java source
src/main/resources  Production resources
src/main/groovy     Production Groovy sources. May also contain Java sources for joint compilation.
src/test/java       Test Java source
src/test/resources  Test resources
src/test/groovy     Test Groovy sources. May also contain Java sources for joint compilation.
```

```